# How to cast to specific object type in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I'm new to Typescript/React/rxJS ecosystem.

I use the following code snippet in my React/Typescript/rxJS application to download a list of users for my proof of concept work:

```
        const githubUsers = `https://api.github.com/users?per_page=1`;
    
        const users$ = ajax.getJSON(githubUsers).pipe(
            map(response => {
                // @ts-ignore
                const user: User = response[0] as User;
                return user;
            }),
            catchError(error => throwError(error))
        );
    
        users$.subscribe(
            response => log.info("User response: ", response),
            error => log.error(error),
            () => log.info("Subscription completed.")
        );
```

The **"log.info"** is my custom built log framework, it can be replaced with **"console.log"** if you want to try it out.

If I leave the "ts-ignore", I have this problem:

```
TS2571: Object is of type 'unknown'.
    72 |         const users$ = ajax.getJSON(githubUsers).pipe(
    73 |             map(response => {
  > 74 |                 const user: User = response[0] as User;
       |                                    ^^^^^^^^
    75 |                 return user;
    76 |             }),
    77 |             catchError(error => throwError(error))
```

So, my question is how can I properly cast this?

I appreciate any help on this.

Comment: The API returns a list of users, therefore you should cast to an array of users rather than mapping the first item in the response to a single user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is already in the logs

`response` object is `unknown`

so, on line 73, use [Type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) and create a temporary variable. Use that array variable later:

```
map(response => {
    const u = response as User[]
    // your logic
```